# Why Pompey didn't die when he entered the Holy of Holies?

Tags: history, beis-hamikdash

During the Siege of Jerusalem at about 63 BC, the Romans managed to conquer the city. And Pompey - the general of this siege [had entered the Holy of Holies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Siege_of_Jerusalem_(63_BC)), which only the High Priest was allowed to enter on Yom Kippur  *(at any other time, he'd die if he stepped in there and, even entering at Yom Kippur wouldn't grant safety since he'd die if he wasn't sacred enough to enter)*.

So if the High Priest could die entering the Holy of Holies, then how is it possible thast Pompey did  not die?

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/31379/why-did-god-do-nothing-against-the-romans-that-desecrated-the-temple

Comment: Sorry. I found another duplicate : https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/127267/pompey-and-the-holy-of-holies?rq=1 , though I indeed did a search before posting but for some reason it didn't come up in my search engine. Thanks!

Comment: Rabbi Ariel Bar Tzadok says The second temple was empty of the holiness of the first as there was no Ark of the covenant, this is also why Prophecy ended. Pompeii entered an empty Holy of Holies